# Rich text box in C# trim and length count

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

RichTextBox C#

When i do a comparison

```
if RichTextBox.Lines.Count() > 2
```

//Do Something

For some reason i get these data stored in rich text box, while i am working on restricting that i need to validate for the screwed up data

```
 [0] - "East coast road"
 [1]- "New York"
 [2] -""
```

This returns count as 3 where in there should be only 2, how do i eliminate that white space next line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to trim the text before doing your comparison

```
RichTextBox.Text = RichTextBox.Text.Trim()
```

Trim removes all white-space characters from the start and end of the string
and the newline is considered a white-space
[See refs from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

if RichTextBox.Lines.Count() > 2

3 > 2 is true

You can iterate and delete on string.isnullorempty

Empty is still a string to you need to delete it or build in logic to not count it